# Consuming third party web service with VS 2010

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services

I need to consume a java web service from a COTS application. I only get the wsdl to consume it. It requires I provide a user name and password. I previously consumed them using WSE 3.0 in my .NET 2005 windows service. I am trying to upgrade the windows service to 2010.

I added the reference to the service through the Add Service.  (I had to change custom names and servers because of company policy so hopefully I did not create syntax errors.) I had to edit the links because this is my first post.

I see it added entries to my app config:

```
<startup><supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/></startup><system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="MyServiceSoapBinding">
                <textMessageEncoding maxReadPoolSize="64" maxWritePoolSize="16"
                    messageVersion="Soap12" writeEncoding="utf-8">
                    <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
                        maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
                </textMessageEncoding>
                <httpTransport manualAddressing="false" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="65536" allowCookies="false" authenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    bypassProxyOnLocal="false" decompressionEnabled="true" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                    keepAliveEnabled="true" maxBufferSize="65536" proxyAuthenticationScheme="Anonymous"
                    realm="" transferMode="Buffered" unsafeConnectionNtlmAuthentication="false"
                    useDefaultWebProxy="true" />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="htp://servername:1234/webservices/thewebservicename"
            binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyServiceSoapBinding"
            contract="MyServiceReference.thewebservicename" name="thewebservicenameSoapPort" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

I first tried using BasicHttpBinding:

```
    Dim Binding As BasicHttpBinding
    Dim Binding As CustomBinding
    Dim EndPoint As EndpointAddress
    Dim etFramework As MyServiceReference.thewebserviceClient
    Dim rsp As MyServiceReference.MethodResponse
    Dim req As MyServiceReference.atkinpovoucherRequest
    Dim rsp1 As MyServiceReference.atkinpovoucherResponse


        Binding = New BasicHttpBinding()
        Binding.Name = "MyServiceSoapBinding"
        Binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Message
        Binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName
        Binding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Mtom
        Binding.ReceiveTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
        Binding.OpenTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
        Binding.CloseTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
        Binding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 5, 0)
        ' Set the transport security to UsernameOverTransport for Plaintext usernames
        EndPoint = New EndpointAddress("htp://server:1234/webservices/thewebservice")
        'Create the SOAP Client (and pass in the endpoint and the binding)
        etFramework = New MyServiceReference.thewebserviceClient(Binding, EndPoint)
        ''Set the username and password
        etFramework.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "theusername"
        etFramework.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "thepassword"
        req = New MyServiceReference.theservicenameRequest(strXMLToSubmit)
        rsp1 = etFramework.MyServiceReference_thewebservice_theservicename(req)
        Debug.WriteLine(rsp1.ToString())
```

I get this error: {"BasicHttp binding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials."}
    System.InvalidOperationException: {"BasicHttp binding requires that BasicHttpBinding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType be equivalent to the BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate credential type for secure messages. Select Transport or TransportWithMessageCredential security for UserName credentials."}

Changing the security Mode just results indifferent errors (Soap header is required; expected https not http ....)

Upon researching, I find I need to use WSHttpBinding. I change the Binding and get error: {"The content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 373 bytes of the response were: 'env:VersionMismatchunable to locate Envelope in namespace http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.  Root element is "htp://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" in namespace "Envelope"'."}
    System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: {"The content type text/xml; charset=utf-8 of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (multipart/related; type="application/xop+xml"). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 373 bytes of the response were: 'env:VersionMismatchunable to locate Envelope in namespace htp://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/.  Root element is "htp://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" in namespace "Envelope"'."}

I researched more and I changed the messageVersion="Soap12" in the app.config to messageVersion="Soap11" and get the same error. I changed the WSMessageEncoding to TEXT and get a similiar error message (binding is application/soap+xml). All research I can find on this seems to be consuming a WCF Service instead of a java.

Any help would be greately appreciated! 
Becca